# Enterprise Linux: VLAN bridges

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, bridge

How do you properly configure vlan bridges on RHEL5 or OEL5?

I've tried the following network-scripts, but no packets are recieved on the bridge. If I add an ip address to vlan60 I'm unable to reach the gateway for that subnet.

If I add the same address to eth0.60 it works fine.

I also notice that vlan60 has hardware address 00:00:00:00:00:00. Shouldnt the bridge inherit the hardware address of the physical controller/vlan interface?

What am I missing?

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.60

```
DEVICE=eth0.60
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
Bridge=vlan60 <-- This one should be BRIDGE=vlan60
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-vlan60

```
DEVICE=vlan60
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Bridge
```

Here's the output from ifconfig, notice the 0 RX packets and the empty hardware address:

```
[root@hydrogen]# ifconfig vlan60
vlan60    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:8512 (8.3 KiB)

[root@hydrogen]# ifconfig eth0.60
eth0.60   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:12:FB:80:0D
          inet addr:192.168.0.201  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:546437 (533.6 KiB)  TX bytes:2283066 (2.1 MiB)
```

Update:

```
[root@hydrogen network-scripts]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vlan60          8000.000000000000       no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from **brctl** lists the bridge, but not the vlan interface (eth0.60)

Turns out the Bridge=vlan60 statement should have BRIDGE in all caps, while the TYPE=Bridge statement should be mixed case. Since I had the first one wrong, the vlan interface was simply never added to the bridge.

Solution: Change Bridge=vlan60 to BRIDGE=vlan60 in ifcfg-eth0.60 and bounce the interface.

```
[root@hydrogen]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vlan60          8000.002612fb800d       no              eth0.60
```